# How to parse and use a json object passed from parent page

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I apologize in advance if this has already been answered. I've Googled around for a few hours now, and I still haven't found anything that seems to answer my exact question.

Here is my code:

```
                  <ion-content>
                        <div class="list">
                            <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" class="item">
                                <div class="row"
                                     ng-repeat="x in orders|orderBy:'order_id'| filter:{ paid: '0' } ">
                                    <div class="col left">
                                        {{x.order_id}}
                                    </div>                                                  <div class="col left">
                                        <a ng-href="#/tab/orderdetails?detail={{x.detail}}">订单详情</a>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
               </ion-content>
```

x.detail is the json object i want to pass to the newly opened page "orderdetails.html":

```
<script id="templates/orderdetails.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="OrderDetails">
        <ion-content class="padding">

            <p>Here I want to display order details...</p>

            var obj = this.href.split('?')[1];
            console.log(obj);

            <p>
                <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            </p>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>
```

app.js:

```
.state('tabs.orderdetails', {
      url: "/orderdetails",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/orderdetails.html"
        }
      }
    })
```

I want to know how to parse and use the passed object in "orderdetails.html". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add controllers to the views,

then declare a $scope.json_name = json value
to be able to use the variable the you angular template

```
 <script id="templates/orderdetails.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="OrderDetails">
        <ion-content class="padding">

            <p>Here I want to display order details...</p>

            this is a variable name: {{ name }}

            <p>
                <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            </p>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>
```

then you can add the controller like this

```
.state('tabs.orderdetails', {
      url: "/orderdetails",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/orderdetails.html",
          controller: function ($scope) {
             $scope.name = "this is a variable name";
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

you can refer to [angular documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I pass x.detail to the views?

Comment: you can adjust this one

 $scope.x = {
    name: "John",
    details: "this is a detail",
    order_id: 123
};

then print in the view this

{{ x.order_id }}

Comment: please check the "ng-repeat" part, x.detail is defined there as input parameter. I pass it using `ng-href="#/tab/orderdetails?detail={{x.detail}}`, but I don't know how to get the value in the views.